# What are some typical use-cases for `Promise.race()`?

Tags: javascript, promise

I try to understand in what kind of situations [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) is useful. Can you please give some typical use-cases?